# Express NodeJS | Express-messages, Express-validator, and Connect-Flash not displaying messages

Tags: express, pug, connect-flash, express-validator

this question is kind of all over the place but basically, it should be displaying messages whenever you login/logout and if you haven't filled in the correct input.

None of the messages come up and I'm not getting any errors but everything else seems to work, your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    // Express Session Middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));


// Express Messages Middleware
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

// Express Validator Middleware
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));
```

Here is the register part

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const password2 = req.body.password2;

  req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not 
match').equals(req.body.password);

  let errors = req.getValidationResult();

if(errors){
    res.render('register', {
      errors:errors
    });
  } else {
    let newUser = new User({
      name:name,
      email:email,
      username:username,
      password:password
    });

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
          } else {
            req.flash('success','You are now registered and can log in');
            res.redirect('/users/login');
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I am using pug and this is the message part

```
.messages
        each type in Object.keys(locals.messages)
          each message in Object.values(locals.messages)
            div(class="alert alert-"+type) #{message}
```

And this is what I put in my layout

```
!= messages('message', locals)
      if errors
        each error, i in errors
          div(class="alert alert-danger") #{error.msg}
```

Sorry if this is confusing, if I need to provide anymore info or fix anything just let me know.